# How do I append to a group of lists in a loop?

Tags: python

I am trying to append to a group of lists using a for loop, but I get an attribute error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Here is my simplified code:

```
Bulkiness = []
Polarity_Z = []
Polarity_G = []

names_of_my_Lists = ['Bulkiness','Polarity_Z','Polarity_G']

count = 1

for list in names_of_my_Lists:
    count = count + 1
    print (count)
    list.append(count)
    
print (Bulkiness)
```

This approach works for dictionaries, so I was surprised that it did not work for another list.  So, how can I append to a large number of differently named lists in a loop?

I am open to other ways of doing this.  The end goal is to make a list that can then be added to an existing Pandas DataFrame as a new column.  Thus, I am already looping within two other loops.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `['Bulkiness','Polarity_Z','Polarity_G']` is obviously list of strings... the error message is quite clear about this too...

Comment: What are you trying to end up with? Because "Thus, I am already looping within two other loops." seems like there must be a better approach, but you've not supplied what you ultimately want to add to the DataFrame.

Comment: Off-topic, but avoid naming your loop variable `list` (it'll shadow the built-in function `list`).

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating a new list `names_of_my_Lists` with three strings `['Bulkiness', 'Polarity_Z', 'Polarity_G']`. An approach will be like this one that can merge the lists into one list.

```
Bulkiness = [1, 2, 3]
Polarity_Z = ['a', 'b', 'c']
Polarity_G = ["Bulkiness", "Polarity_Z", "Polarity_G"]

merge_list = [Bulkiness, Polarity_Z, Polarity_G]

for lst in merge_list:
    print(lst)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3]
['a', 'b', 'c']
['Bulkiness', 'Polarity_Z', 'Polarity_G']
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I think you are trying to count lists in your merged list and append that count to Bulkiness? Am I right?

```
Bulkiness = []
Polarity_Z = []
Polarity_G = []
#get rid of '' from your list to merge list not a string
names_of_my_Lists = [Bulkiness, Polarity_Z, Polarity_G]

count = 1 # usually count starts at 0

# change list to lst
for lst in names_of_my_Lists:
    count += 1
    print (count)
    # you were appending to list, but such list doesn't exist in your code
    # I am assuming you want to append to Bulkiness
    Bulkiness.append(count)
    
print(Bulkiness)

Print Output:
2
3
4
[2, 3, 4]
```

Printing each count, and then the list of them. Not really sure what are you trying to achieve, as you are printing Bulkiness and name would suggest me this is a 'bulkiness' of your merged list (but that list contains Bulkiness as well). That's why I've changed list.append() to Bulkiness.append() (assuming that's where you want to append count as you are printing that list).

Your attribute error came from iterating over a list of strings and then trying to append count to those strings.

Another thing you may be trying to do is this:

```
Bulkiness = []
Polarity_Z = []
Polarity_G = []

names_of_my_Lists = [Bulkiness, Polarity_Z, Polarity_G]

count = 1

for lst in names_of_my_Lists:
    count = count + 1
    print (count)
    lst.append(count)

print(Bulkiness)

Print Output:
2
3
4
[2]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

My intent was to append to each list in turn using a for loop.  The for loop would contain another for loop so that each list would have several thousand values in each list.  Then the list would become a new column in a dataframe.

Your code works and it was the ' ' around each list name that was messing me up.

As you stated in your code
(#get rid of '' from your list to merge list not a string)

Thanks again